# export list as shp in R

Tags: shapefile, r, list

I have a list of coordinates with which i can create a path and I want to export this list as shp. I have "shapefiles" package but I didn't find the way to do this. Is there a way to do this with this package or I need something else?I use  R
[image: list of coordinates of nodes]

[image: spatial point data.frame of my list 1]

[image: spatial point data.frame of my list 2]

[image: result of 2 points]

Comment: It's going to be pretty painful typing up all that code in order to work with your example data. In future, maybe consider including the code itself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example to create a `SpatialLinesDataFrame`, which can be saved as a shapefile with `rgdal::writeOGR()`:

```
# create example data set
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(stats::rnorm(2000), ncol = 2)
ch <- chull(dat)
coords <- dat[ch, ]
plot(dat, pch=19)
lines(coords, col="red")
```

[image: example data]

```
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
sp_line <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(coords)), ID=1)))
# set coordinate reference system with SpatialLines(..., proj4string=CRS(...))
# e.g. CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
sp_line_df <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(sp_line, data=data.frame(ID=1))
writeOGR(sp_line_df, "chull", layer="chull", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .Is the same if I have a list of vectors?? I want to export the content of a plot and I only get the points of nodes.

Comment: Can you provide an example data set?

Comment: i edited my first post. as you can see i have a list of vectors with coordinates on nodes from a path. I converted my list to SpatialPointDataFrame and as a result i have only 2 points and not a line shp.